# Copy elements from one memory to other

Tags: c, optimization

I got this question in interview, it seems simple one but I want to confirm my understanding about its functioning.

```
f (char *p, char *q, int n)
{
    int i1 = n >> 2;
    int i2 = n & 3;

    switch (i2) 
    {
        do {
            *q++ = *p++;
            case 3:  *q++ = *p++;
            case 2:  *q++ = *p++;
            case 1:  *q++ = *p++;
            case 0:  ;
        } while (i1--);
    }
}
```

I was asked below questions in interview:

1. What this function does?
2. Why would somebody write such convoluted code?
3. Is there any way to write it differently (simpler, faster)?

Answers given:

1. This function copies the number of elements from the memory where *P is pointing to the memory where *q is pointing.
2. if you will write it with for loop as below (writing only loop)

   ```
   for(i=0;i<n;i++)
      *q++ = *p++;
   ```

   then the compiler taking more MIPS/time in condition checking. In this it will first subtract i from n and then checks is I non zero ? In the given code while loop maintain condition only 1 condition if i1 is non-zero ? So in while loop there is less condition checking.
3. We can write as:

   ```
   f (char *p, char *q, int n)
   {
     for(i=n;i--;)
       *q++ = *p++;
   }
   ```

   It seems simple and faster to me.

Please give me your opinion.

Comment: A good advice - before you post here code, write it in a text editor on your computer, then copy it to your question. This way you can notice some typeos, and get the indention right.

Comment: It looks like someone is wrongly edited your code?
it should be do{switch(){..};}while();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First in your answer you don't seem to take into account that n>>2 integer-divides n by 4 before looping.
Then, you don't check the second condition, which is that if n % 4 == 0, to not copy the value.

- copies 7 bytes and ignores the 8th byte for n/4 bytes from p to q;
- it's very efficient at doing what it does. Using &3 instead of %4 is most likely much faster, and using >> 2 instead of /4 might be faster; only might because it is possible that either the compiler or the c language is designed to automatically make that optimization for you;
- I would give something like that

  ```
  f (char *p, char *q, int n)
  {
  int i1 = n >> 2; //i1 = n / 3;
  int i2 = n & 3;  //i2 = n & 0b111 = n % 4;

  for(; i1 + 1 ; --i) {
      *q++ = *p++;
      if (i2) *q++ = *p++;            
      } 
  }
  ```
- mentionning that the for loop is easier to understand and just as
  efficient,
- and that changing the switch statement for a single if
  statement is cleaner and most likely of similar performance.
- I would then conclude by noting that I added comments on the bitwise
  operations to make their function clearer.